# Polynomial interpolation as an operator on function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods

This is more of an open ended question that popped into my head. Let's think about the act of interpolating a function as an operator on function spaces.

For instance, take $[0,1]$ and the space Banach space of continuous functions $(C([0,1]), |\cdot|_\infty)$ defined on this interval with the supremum norm. Fix a partition $\mathscr{P}$ of this interval. Let $n = \#\mathscr{P}$ be the number of points in this partition and $\mathcal{P}_{n-1}$ be the space of degree $n-1$ polynomials, again a Banach space with the supremum norm. Consider the operator:

$$
I_{\mathscr{P}}:C([0,1])\to \mathcal{P}_{n-1}
$$
such that $I_\mathscr{P}(f)$ is the polynomial that interpolates $f$ in the sense that it interpolates the data points $(x_k, f(x_k))_{x_k\in\mathscr{P}}$. I would like to understand some properties of this operator, for instance:

1. Is it continuous?
2. Can we calculate the norm if this operator?
3. Can we say that, for a sufficiently fine partition, the norm of this operator is close to 1?
4. Any of the above properties is true if we restrict the operator to some space like $C^k([0,1])$, $1\leq k\leq \infty$?

In general, my goal was to find a method to get finite dimensional representations of functions in a way that such a "projection" operator has norm $\leq 1$. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Trivial observation: If $\mathscr{P}=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, then $\mathcal P_{n-1}\to\mathbb R^n,\,p\mapsto(p(x_1),\dots,p(x_n))$ is a vector space isomorphism. Thus the norm on $\mathcal P_{n-1}$ is equivalent to say $\sum_{k=1}^n |p(x_k)|$. Since $f\mapsto f(x_k)$ is continuous for every $k$, so is $I_{\mathscr P}$.

Comment: Coming more from a numerical analysis viewpoint, this seems to be related to the problem of optimizing the choice of interpolation nodes. This problem has been studied extensively (see for instance [https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society/volume-83/issue-5/Optimization-of-the-norm-of-the-Lagrange-interpolation-operator/bams/1183539484.full] (Optimization of the norm of the Lagrange interpolation operator) ).